# avahi-autoipd not able to aquire ipv4ll link local address

Tags: linux

I am facing problem with acquiring link local address(ipv4ll). I am following the below procedure to achieve that.

First, setting proper routes to use link local addressing.

```
 $ route add default dev eth0 metric 99
 $ route add -net 169.254.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 dev eth0 metric 99
```

These routes are set properly. No issues here.

Then I am using avahi-autoipd to discover valid link local address as below

```
$ avahi-autoipd --daemonize --syslog --wait eth0
```

This gives the error –

**Could not receive return value from daemon process.**

I am trying to execute these commands on embedded linux platform. I have made a local network by connecting two embedded linux platforms.

Any idea why this might be happening????

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this.
A new user "avahi-autoipd" need to be added in /var/lib as shown below.

$ adduser avahi-autoipd -h /var/lib/avahi-autoipd

Now check in

$ cat /etc/passwd

You will find a new user with home directory path set in above command

then,

$ avahi-autoipd eth0 &

Now reboot,

$ reboot

Do 'ps' to see all processes

u will find something like this

750 avahi-au  1860 S    avahi-autoipd: [eth0] bound 169.254.11.49

751 root      1780 S    avahi-autoipd: [eth0] callout dispatcher

I hope anyone will find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error.

Ran strace with my command: `strace avahi-autoipd eth0`

and saw:

```
chown32("/var/lib/avahi-autoipd", 1000, 1000) = -1 ENOENT # (No such file or directory)                                                                       

stat64("/var/lib/avahi-autoipd", 0x3ed58c28) = -1 ENOENT # (No such file or directory)
```

Ended up just rebuilding the folder for `/var/lib/avahi-autoipd` and everything worked afterwards.